# Is this a Borel summable $ S = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (k!)a_k $ with $ a_k$ alternating sequence?

Tags: generating-functions, power-series, divergent-series, infinite-sequences

let  $ S = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (k!)a_k $  a divergent series such that  $b_k=(-1)^k (k!)a_k >0 $ for $k>1$  , and $b_k$ signed [this](https://oeis.org/A214645/list)  from $k=1$ to $20$ ,The asymptotic  of the titled series is :$$ A(x) = x + x^2/2! + 3*x^3/3! + 16*x^4/4! + 126*x^5/5! + 1333*x^6/6!+\cdots$$

> > **Question:**
> >     Is this : $ S = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (k!)a_k $ a Borel summable  with $ a_k$ altern sequence?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Note**:This is not an answer but probably helping you to get the answer of your question.just to show some properties related to your formel series .
we denote by $f$ your divergent power series
,The formel series you have is non analytic function and it is smooth ,it's has a positive radius of convergence.Then, it extends uniquely by analytic continuation to a maximally-defined analytic function , Note that the Taylor series of $f$ at $0$ has non-negative coefficients, and it's seems the coefficients are not grow fast that is one of the weaker condition to judge that the formel series you have can be Borel summable